# Not updating state with provider after patch/update, Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-provider

It seems my UI is not updating the changes after I have patched the info over the API. I'm using `Provider` for state management. Here is the code:

**UPDATE**: Changed the data to be an object as send it as one to the API endpoint

UserModel :

```
class UserData{
  String name,
      surname,
      birthDate;

  UserData({
    this.generalEmail,
    this.surname,
    this.primaryPhone,
  });

  UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name= json['name'];
    surname = json['surname'];
    birthDate= json['birthDate'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['surname'] = this.surname;
    data['birthDate'] = this.birthDate;

    return data;
  }
}
```

User Store:

```
class UserStore extends ChangeNotifier {

  Map<String, UserData> _userInfo = {};
  Map<String, UserData> get userInfo => _userInfo ;

 void updateUserInfo(UserData user) {
    _userInfo[user.userId] = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

UserData  getUserInfoByUserId(String userId) => _userInfo[userId];
}
```

And the service action for the User Store:

```
  UserStore userStore;

  BuildContext context;

  UserActions(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userStore = Provider.of<UserStore>(context, listen: false);
  }

Future<HTTPResponse<UserData>> patchUserInfo(UserData user) async {
    final response = await ApiRequest(Method.PATCH, '/users',
        body: jsonEncode(user.toJson()));
    dynamic body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dynamic data = body['data'];
      UserData user = UserData();
      if (data != null) {
        user = UserData.fromJson(data);
      }
      return HTTPResponse<UserData>(
        isSuccessful: true,
        data: user,
        message: HTTPResponse.successMessage,
        statusCode: response.statusCode,
      );
    } else {
      return HTTPResponse<UserData>(
        isSuccessful: false,
        data: null,
        message: body['message'] ?? HTTPResponse.errorMessage,
        statusCode: response.statusCode,
      );
    }
  }

 Future<void> changeUserInfo(UserData user) async {
    final userRes = await patchUserInfo( // call the API and pass the data
        user);
    if (userRes != null) {
      userStore.updateUserInfo(user);
      return;
    }
    userStore.updateUserInfo(user);
  }
```

UI that is not updating:

```
final userStore = Provider.of<UserStore>(context, listen: false);
    UserData user = userStore.getUserInfo(userId);
...
return Column(
children: [
    Text(user.name), // only updates it when I refresh the widget
    Text(user.surname), // only updates it when I refresh the widget
    Text(user.birthDate), // only updates it when I refresh the widget
   ],
);
```

After the API goes through, I want to update my UI with the latest changes if not, don't update the UI. I'm not sure, but it's probably the `updateUserInfo` method inside the UserStore that I'm not setting right in order to update the UI immediately after the successful API call. Where is my mistake? I can use `indexWhere` when it's a list, but how do I update it then when the data model is a `Map` like I defined it in the UserStore?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not listening to the changes in your `Provider` (see: `listen: false`). You can use the following code to get notified upon changes you make with `updateUserInfo`:

```
return Consumer<UserStore>(builder: (context, UserStore userStore, child) {
  UserData user = userStore.getUserInfo(userId);
  return Column(
    children: [
      Text(user.name),
      Text(user.surname), 
      Text(user.birthDate),
    ],
  );
});
```

And use this when you get data from API (since here you don't need to listen):

```
context.read<UserStore>().updateUserInfo(userRes);
```

Create a provider like this, above the `Consumer`:

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserStore(), child: ...);
```